# Using this code in a laboration

Tags: java, arrays, combobox

I had an assignment to try to describe what the following piece of code is doing and I have tried to Google it but I do not understand the different functions. I also can't understand what is actually happening here. So please, help to understand what this code is doing. I will be really grateful for an answer. Here is the code:

```
package edu.hihglevel.station1;

public final class Conveyor extends Station1Component {

private void moveConveyorForwards() {
    combo.setValue_PIN_29(true);
}

private void moveConveyorBackwards() {
    combo.setValue_PIN_30(true);
}

private void stopConveyor() {
    combo.setValue_PIN_29(false);
    combo.setValue_PIN_30(false);
}

public boolean isPartAtPuncher() {
    return combo.isValue_PIN_23();
}

public boolean isPartAtBeginning() {
    return combo.isValue_PIN_22();
}

public void ejectFromPuncher() {
    if (isPartAtPuncher()) {
        moveConveyorForwards();
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - now < 2000) {
            sleep(1);
        }
        stopConveyor();
    }
}

public void moveFromEntryToPuncher() {
    if (isPartAtBeginning()) {
        while (!isPartAtPuncher()) {
            moveConveyorForwards();
        }
    }
    stopConveyor();

}
}
```

Comment: This isn't the proper use of Stack Overflow.

Comment: How is this javascript?

Comment: Looks like setting hardware (PIN) values of a robotical vehicle (conveyor, maybe a train) for different actions of moving, docking in and out of some kind of docking station (puncher?) and related actions…

Comment: what is this row "combo.setValue_PIN_29(true);" doing?